# CKAN datastore API number of records limited to 1500

Tags: ckan

I have uploaded a .xls file as a dataset resource to my ckan instance and have no problem downloading it with its full content.

The problem is that in the preview table only the first 1500 rows shows up (the file contains 23 000 rows). The same problem occurs when fetching records from ckan datastore API.

The following request returns the first 1500 records (as expected):

```
{domain url}/api/3/action/datastore_search?limit=1500&resource_id=413f4b95-a49c-4ae2-a6e2-1c9a8d2ab984
```

But when I try to find the next 1500 records, none are returned!

```
{domain url}/api/3/action/datastore_search?offset=1500&limit=1500&resource_id=413f4b95-a49c-4ae2-a6e2-1c9a8d2ab984
```

My question: is there a limit of number of record that can be uploaded to the datastore? I have found no information on this on ckan.org, the official documentation (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/) or in the mailing list (https://lists.okfn.org/mailman/listinfo/ckan-dev). Is there any configuration that can be made?

I have a CKAN 2.1 installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any limit on datastore records. We successfully upload more than 4 million records on inventory.data.gov

Check out here, preview may take little bit longer to load

https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/national-center-for-education-statistics-nces-integrated-postsecondary-education-data-system-ipeds-a/resource/6d2a0324-5964-44c3-97be-061c0eb5fcc9

https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/veterans-burial-sites-1404404968/resource/53a0824d-2236-4c22-9dc8-9ac59b05285d

Having said that we did noticed behavior you mentioned ... I guess is its most likely due some error that occurred during upload. You can check the exact details under Datastore tab on edit resource page.